# How to properly sort a normal US date using the JS Data Tables plugin

Tags: javascript, php, date, datatables

I have a batch of dates in the format `mm/dd/yyyy` and associated names that need to be sorted with data tables. These dates are echod in a loop using PHP. My code (`index.php`) looks like this:

```
<!--
    Assume datatables plugin is loaded, and
    a PHP var named $arr is loaded and has the
    structure:
        $arr['mm/dd/yyyy'] => 'name'
-->
<table class="table cdates">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php 
        foreach($arr as $date => $name){
    ?>
        <tr class="crow">
           <td><?php echo $date; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Inside of a javascript file, named `cdatatable.js` that has already been loaded, I have the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.cdates').DataTable({
        pageLength:25,
        responsive:true,
        dom: '<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp',
        buttons: [
            {extend: 'copy'},
            {extend: 'csv'},
            {extend: 'excel', title: 'name'},
            {extend: 'pdf', title: 'name'},

            {extend: 'print',
                customize: function (win){
                    $(win.document.body).css('font-size', '10px');

                    $(win.document.body).find('table')
                            .addClass('compact')
                            .css('font-size', 'inherit');
                }
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

The datatables will properly sort the name, but unfortunately, it treats the date as a string and therefore sorts it by digit. For example if I have the following table:

```
Date        Name
--------- | -------
01/02/2003  My Name
12/01/2012  Hello world
06/20/2002  Name 2
```

And I sort it by `Date`, it currently returns:

```
Date        Name
--------- | -------
01/02/2003  My Name
06/20/2002  Name 2
12/01/2012  Hello world
```

It should be returning:

```
Date        Name
--------- | -------
06/20/2002  Name 2
01/02/2003  My Name
12/01/2012  Hello world
```

I've seen tons of other questions about sorting different countries dates, however none seemed to really apply to me. I've also tried converting the string to a date in JS and then applying that value to the row. It doesn't seem to work though and the same issue happens.

Is there a way in PHP that I could convert my date to one that can be recognized in JavaScript maybe? Or if that isn't possible, is there something I can add to dataTables to recognize my column as a "date" column?

Comment: What is the sorting of the PHP array? I mean if the JS DataTable method doesn't do anything with sorting (it looks so) the wrong sorting is in your PHP array. Sort your dates in the PHP part

Comment: If you use YYYY-MM-DD then they sort nicely as strings.

Comment: @user907860 `datatables` lets you sort data the way you want though. It isn't a fixed thing. The problem ended up being that JavaScript's `Date.parse()` could not recognize a date in the format of `mm/dd/yyyy` and so it treated it as a string. Since `"01" < "06" < "12"` alphabetically, it would sort it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to replace this line:

```php
<td><?php echo $date; ?></td>
```

with the line below:

```php
<td data-order="<?php echo strtotime($date); ?>"><?php echo $date; ?></td>
```

Another solution would be to modify [date-uk](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/date-uk) plug-in to accept date in `mm/dd/YYYY` format but solution shown above would be easier and possibly faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="table cdates">
    <thead>
        <tr>Date</tr>
        <tr>Name</tr>
    </thead>
```

should be

```
<table class="table cdates">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I was posting a minimal example and forgot to format it correctly. The code has been updated!

Comment: :( I was hoping that was the problem, guess not

Comment: It's alright! The `data-order` trick worked. I just had to create a hidden date in the format of `YYYY-mm-dd`